# How to access JSP variables inside the angular js constants

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp

i have a module with the constants

`angular,module('myconstants',[]).constant('url','<%=MyBean.getUrl("uri-prefix")');`

When i'm using this url constant,  it is showing as a string('`<%=MyBean.getUrl("uri-prefix")');`), but actually it should call the MyBean.getUrl method.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access variables in JSP file, you can modify like code below

```
angular,module('myconstants',[]).constant('url','<%=MyBean.getUrl("uri-prefix")');

angular,module('myconstants',[]).constant('url','<%=MyBean.getUrl("uri-prefix")%>');
```

But If code is placed outside JSP file, you can use global variable to access variables.

you can type code below (in a JSP file)

```
<script>
url = '<%=MyBean.getUrl("uri-prefix")%>'
</script>
```

then you can access (in other javascript files)

```
angular.module('myconstants',[]).constant('url',url);
```

Comment: sorry for the typo in my question , `angular,module('myconstants',[]).constant('url','<%=MyBean.getUrl("uri-prefix")%>');`  i was using the same in my code and i was getting the error, let me try with the global variables

Comment: Keep in mind that JSP is a server-side display technology, and that if your Java servlet container is configured properly, it will execute before your any Javascript.  In other words, JSP code is often used to render both HTML and Javascript, and then the browser will execute the Javascript (assuming it's rendered correctly).